# Multicast Datagram Packet Not Recevied

Tags: java, sockets, server, multicast, datagram

I am running a messenger program with both server and clients on the same host (a mac pro pc). The uni-cast connection between the server and client works as expected on the same host. A client sends a message to the server via uni-cast connection. The server sends the message to a multi-cast address. Clients listen to the multi-cast address and suppose to receive the message from the server.

The multi-cast connection doesn't work as expected.The server sends the message without any exception but clients don't receive the message via multi-cast. Here are the code snippet for sender and receiver.

```
public interface SocketMessengerConstants 
{   
// address for multicast datagrams
public static final String MULTICAST_ADDRESS = "239.0.0.1";

// port for listening for multicast datagrams
public static final int MULTICAST_LISTENING_PORT = 5555;

// port for sending multicast datagrams
public static final int MULTICAST_SENDING_PORT = 5554; 
......   

public class MulticastSender implements Runnable
{   
  private byte[] messageBytes; // message data

  public MulticastSender( byte[] bytes ) 
  {  
   messageBytes = bytes; // create the message
  } // end MulticastSender constructor

   // deliver message to MULTICAST_ADDRESS over DatagramSocket
  public void run() 
  {  
   try // deliver message
   {         
     // create DatagramSocket for sending message
     DatagramSocket socket = 
        new DatagramSocket( MULTICAST_SENDING_PORT );

     // use InetAddress reserved for multicast group
     InetAddress group = InetAddress.getByName( MULTICAST_ADDRESS );

     // create DatagramPacket containing message
     System.out.println(messageBytes.length);
     DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket( messageBytes, 
        messageBytes.length, group, MULTICAST_LISTENING_PORT );

     socket.send( packet ); // send packet to multicast group
     socket.close(); // close socket
    } // end try
    catch ( IOException ioException ) 
    { 
     ioException.printStackTrace();
    } // end catch
  } // end method run
} // end class MulticastSender


public class PacketReceiver implements Runnable 
{
 private MessageListener messageListener; // receives messages
 private MulticastSocket multicastSocket; // receive broadcast messages
 private InetAddress multicastGroup; // InetAddress of multicast group
 private boolean keepListening = true; // terminates PacketReceiver

 public PacketReceiver( MessageListener listener ) 
 {
  messageListener = listener; // set MessageListener

  try // connect MulticastSocket to multicast address and port 
  {
     // create new MulticastSocket
     multicastSocket = new MulticastSocket(
        MULTICAST_LISTENING_PORT );

     // use InetAddress to get multicast group
     multicastGroup = InetAddress.getByName( MULTICAST_ADDRESS );

     // join multicast group to receive messages
     multicastSocket.joinGroup( multicastGroup ); 

     // set 5 second timeout when waiting for new packets
     multicastSocket.setSoTimeout( 5000 );
   } // end try
   catch ( IOException ioException ) 
   {
     ioException.printStackTrace();
   } // end catch
  } // end PacketReceiver constructor

 // listen for messages from multicast group 
 public void run() 
 {          
  // listen for messages until stopped
  while ( keepListening ) 
  {
     // create buffer for incoming message
     byte[] buffer = new byte[ MESSAGE_SIZE ];

     // create DatagramPacket for incoming message
     DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket( buffer, 
        MESSAGE_SIZE );

     try // receive new DatagramPacket (blocking call)
     {            
        multicastSocket.receive( packet ); 
     } // end try
     catch ( SocketTimeoutException socketTimeoutException ) 
     {
        continue; // continue to next iteration to keep listening
     } // end catch
     catch ( IOException ioException ) 
     {
        ioException.printStackTrace();
        break;
     } // end catch

     // put message data in a String
     String message = new String( packet.getData() );

     message = message.trim(); // trim whitespace from message
     System.out.println(message);

     // tokenize message to retrieve user name and message body
     StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer( 
        message, MESSAGE_SEPARATOR );

     // ignore messages that do not contain a user 
     // name and message body
     if ( tokenizer.countTokens() == 2 ) 
     {
        // send message to MessageListener
        messageListener.messageReceived( 
           tokenizer.nextToken(), // user name
           tokenizer.nextToken() ); // message body
     } // end if
   } // end while

   try 
   {
     multicastSocket.leaveGroup( multicastGroup ); // leave group
     multicastSocket.close(); // close MulticastSocket
   } // end try
   catch ( IOException ioException )
   { 
     ioException.printStackTrace();
   } // end catch
} // end method run

......
} // end class PacketReceiver
```

Multi-cast feature was disabled on the router. I unchecked "Disable IGMP Proxying" from router's gateway. But multi-cast datagram packet is still not received.

Update: The program was behind firewall. After the firewall permits incoming connections, everything works as expected.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that actual multi-cast has to be enabled on hardware.  Most routers won't allow the protocol.  I might be wrong, but I'm pretty sure that's the way it is.  Sorry about that.

Comment: Multi-cast feature was disabled on the router. I unchecked "Disable IGMP Proxying" from router's gateway. Thanks. But multi-cast datagram packet is still not received.

Comment: Does it work when you use udp broadcasts instead? What kind of network do you have? Some complicated corporate network with multiple vlans and routers or just some home network? When you fire up Wireshark for example, do you see the packets?

Comment: The program runs on home network. I saw the udp packets being sent from Wireshark capture.